# How do I add relative hyperlinks to a group of pdf files using pdfbox?

Tags: c#, pdf, hyperlink, relative-path, pdfbox

I am currently implementing functionality to parse a group of pdf's to retrieve each pdfs meta data.And then interlink these by adding hyperlinks links to each pdf wherever another pdf is being referenced inside it.I am able to create absolute hyperlinks.But after these pdfs are uploaded to a server, then they can be downloaded from server to any local machine path.I want these hyperlinks  to work after they are downloaded to a different location.So, how can create hyperlinks which are relative the group of pdfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which solved my issue :

```
PDActionRemoteGoTo remoteGoto = new PDActionRemoteGoTo();
PDComplexFileSpecification fileDesc = new PDComplexFileSpecification();
fileDesc.setFile(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath));
                            remoteGoto.setOpenInNewWindow(true);
                            remoteGoto.setFile(fileDesc);
                            txtLink.setAction(remoteGoto);
 txtLink.setRectangle(rect);
 page.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);
```