# How do I convert a file path to a device independent path using c#?

Tags: c#, pdf, hyperlink, filepath

I am implementing functionality to add hyperlinks to a pdf.Initially I was adding hyperlinks to pdf by first converting them to URI and then converting that URI to string.But problem with this approach is that it opens the hyperlink files in browser.I want the files to opened by their corresponding default application.Hence someone suggested me to use device independent paths,which are like :

> /C/MyFolder/MyFile.pdf

So, is there any function in c# which I can use to convert normal file paths to device independent paths.

Comment: Default application and device independent path have nothing to do with each other...

Comment: But normal file paths are not accepted as hyperlinks and uri paths open files in browser.So, how do I make hyperlinks for pdf file open in adobe acrobat reader?

Comment: Try searching a little better and paste some code. With this long question with no shown effort no one is going to help you

Comment: Quite often I tend to use Process.Start("YourAppName.exe", pathToFile);

Comment: @VK. I may have misunderstood your original question. Are these hyperlinks from a PDF to a PDF or from an HTML page to a PDF?

Comment: @joelgeraci these are hyperlinks from a pdf to a pdf.

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer because I don't know C# but I'm sure there's a replace function or regular expression that will do the trick.

Comment: This issue was solved with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42130022/4720757) answer.